# Javascript CORS fetch response.status = 0

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch

I am making a fetch-request from domain A to an image on domain B.
I have setup the correct headers on domain B (Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*)

Now if i validate the response-status (response.status) i always get status 0.
However if i check in the chrome-debugger i can see the image was received with status 200.

.

My use-case is to decide wether or not to cache the resource based on the status code. Since domain B only contains static resources and the cache is supposed to be permanent, i consider it's better not to cache (yet) if the status-code is not correct.

Does anyone know why i get this behaviour?

Edit:

- Both domains are https
- This is the code snippet:

  ```
  fetch(e.request).then(function(response){
   console.log(e.request.url+' - '+response.status);
  }
  ```

Comment: `However if i check in the chrome-debugger i can see the image was received with status 200` - can you also see the CORS response header? status 0 usually means a CORS issue

Comment: cors response header was indeed available, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I have found the answer myself, i've been struggling with this already for a few hours.

The e.request was originating from a serviceworker, and it seems the request-mode is set default to 'navigate'. This has to be 'cors'

I've created a new request like this:

```
var request = new Request(e.request.url, {
  method: e.request.method,
  headers: e.request.headers,
  mode: 'cors',
  redirect: 'manual'});
```

It does seem strange to me that cors-content is allowed without the cors-mode, but the status-code is modified nevertheless.

If someone knows what could be the reasoning behind this?